# Понимание запроса - Select 1 from

Tags: postgresql

**Задача:**

Найти сотрудника с самой высокой зарплатой среди каждого отдела

**Данные:**

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE employee_id_seq; 

create table Employee
(
    id_emp    int DEFAULT nextval('employee_id_seq')
                           NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
    name_emp  varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    mgr_id_fk int          not null,

    job_emp   text         NOT NULL, 
    salary    int          NOT NULL,
    date_emp  date         NOT NULL,
    dep_ID_fk int          NOT NULL
);

ALTER SEQUENCE employee_id_seq
    OWNED BY employee.id_emp; 

create table Manager
(
    id_mgr   int not null primary key unique,
    type_mgr varchar(255)
);

ALTER table Employee
    add FOREIGN KEY (mgr_id_fk) REFERENCES Manager (id_mgr)
        on update cascade 
        on delete set null;

create table Department
(
    id_depart   int          NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY unique,
    name_depart varchar(255) not null,
    address     text,
    phone       text
);

insert into Manager (id_mgr, type_mgr)
VALUES
       (1006, 'juniormgr'),
       (1004, 'middlemgr'),
       (1005, 'seniormgr');

insert into Department (id_depart, name_depart, address, phone)
values (1, 'Sales', 'Sydney', '0425 198 053'),
       (2, 'Accounts', 'Melbourne', '0429 198 955'),
       (3, 'Admin', 'Melbourne', '0428 198 758'),
       (4, 'Marketing', 'Sydney', '0427 198 757');


insert into Employee(id_emp, name_emp, mgr_id_fk, job_emp, salary, date_emp, dep_ID_fk)
values (nextval('employee_id_seq'), 'ken Adams', 1006, 'Salesman', 70000, '2008-04-12', 1),
       (nextval('employee_id_seq'), 'Ru Jones', 1004, 'Salesman', 65000, '2010-01-18', 1),
       (nextval('employee_id_seq'), 'Dhal Sim', 1006, 'Accountant', 88000, '2001-03-07', 2),
       (nextval('employee_id_seq'), 'Ellen Honda', 1006, 'Manager', 118000, '2001-03-17', 1),
       (nextval('employee_id_seq'), 'Mike Bal', 1005, 'Receptionist', 68000, '2006-06-21', 3),
       (nextval('employee_id_seq'), 'Martin Bison', 1005, 'CEO', 210000, '2010-07-12', 3),
       (nextval('employee_id_seq'), 'Shen Li', 1004, 'Salesman', 86000, '2014-09-18', 1),
       (nextval('employee_id_seq'), 'Zang Ross', 1004, 'Salesman', 65000, '2017-02-02', 1),
       (nextval('employee_id_seq'), 'Sagar Kahn', 1005, 'Salesman', 70000, '2016-03-01', 1);
```

Вот такой запрос выдаст нужную информацию :

```sql
select * from employee e
where not exists (select 1 from employee e2
                  where e2.dep_id_fk = e.dep_id_fk
                    and e2.salary > e.salary);
```

Мои рассуждения:

1. Сначала выполнится подзапрос и Postgres сохранит этот временный результат
2. затем будет выполнится остальная часть запроса

```sql
select * from employee e
where not exists ...
```

где **not exists** исключит все совпадения найденные в подзапросе

**Вопрос :**

Данный код вызывает непонимание, как же все таки это работает, потому что здесь все не логично на мой взгляд.

Например, как работает вот это

```sql
select 1 from employee e2
                  where e2.dep_id_fk = e.dep_id_fk
                    and e2.salary > e.salary
```

**select 1 from**  - что он вообще делает ?

**e2.dep_id_fk = e.dep_id_fk** - это проверка одной и той же таблицы ( в подзапросе и в основном запросе), но зачем ?

**e2.salary > e.salary** - а это вот зачем ?

**Кто-нибудь может подробно пояснить** эти моменты, особенно применение **select 1 from**

### Обновление (на основе комментариев):

**снова мои рассуждения:**

**select 1 from employee e2** - сама по себе, это строка будет возвращать по одной записи и сравнивать их с записями каждой строки из внешнего запроса (выражение-пустышка, только чтобы взять для перебора строку)

**e2.salary > e.salary**  - например, найдены записи с одинаковым департаментом и несколькими разными зарплатами в конкретном департаменте.
Из **под-запроса** выбирается некий **департамент** и сравнивается с департаментом из внешнего запроса и когда найдется соответствие, тогда происходит сравнение зарплат между сотрудниками данного департамента :

```sql
where 3(подзапрос) = 3 (внешний запрос)
                    and 210 000 (подзапрос) > 68 000 (внешний запрос)
```

результат будет **true**, но **not exists**, инвертирует его в **false**, поэтому такая запись не попадет в результирующий (внешний) запрос;

```sql
where 3(подзапрос) = 3 (внешний запрос)
                    and 210 000 (подзапрос) > 210 000 (внешний запрос)
```

результат будет **false**, но **not exists**, инвертирует его в **true**, поэтому такая запись попадет в результирующий (внешний) запрос и это будет запись о сотруднике с максимальной зп для текущего департамента;

Answer (score 2):

> Мои рассуждения:
>
> Сначала выполнится подзапрос и Postgres сохранит этот временный результат

Неверно. Подзапрос будет выполняться для каждой отдельной записи первой копии таблицы. Конечно, реально запрос может быть выполнен иначе, но логика SQL-текста именно такая.

> select 1 from - что он вообще делает ?

`WHERE EXISTS` просто проверяет, что запись существует. `WHERE NOT EXISTS` просто проверяет, что записи не существует.

При это абсолютно всё равно, что в той записи - важен сам факт её существования. Можно в SELECT писать что угодно - единицу, ноль, строку, дату, NULL... значение всё равно будет проигнорировано. Будет зарегистрирован только факт, что запись нашлась или не нашлась.

> e2.dep_id_fk = e.dep_id_fk - это проверка одной и той же таблицы ( в подзапросе и в основном запросе), но зачем ?
>
> e2.salary > e.salary - а это вот зачем ?

Это условия коррелированного подзапроса, который будет выполняться на второй копии таблицы (обращаю внимание - абсолютно независимой, словно это другая таблица) для каждой записи из первой копии.

То есть подзапрос (вместе с NOT EXISTS) смотрит, есть ли в таблице запись с тем же департаментом, что у текущей записи, и бОльшей зарплатой. Понятно, что для любой записи, где зарплата не максимальна, такая запись найдётся, NOT EXISTS вернёт FALSE, и запись не будет возвращена. А для той записи, где зарплата максимальна, записи с ещё бОльшей зарплатой не найдётся, NOT EXISTS вернёт TRUE, и запрос вернёт эту запись.